# Can I make two requests to the clicky API using just one File() call or similar?

Tags: php

I am making a call to the clicky API as follows:

```
$href = urlencode( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] );
$title = urlencode( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] );
$ref = urlencode( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
$ua = urlencode( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );

file("necessary clicky API call to clicky id );
```

But we need to make a call from one page to two different clicky accounts:

```
$href = urlencode( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] );
$title = urlencode( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] );
$ref = urlencode( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
$ua = urlencode( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );

file("necessary clicky API call to clicky id X );

file("necessary clicky API call to clicky id Y );
```

Is there anyway in PHP to do that without making use of the file() function twice? It seems like it would be optimal to log both in one connection if that is an option, but I am not sure if it is possible?

Is the lag time of two connections perhaps not a worry? That's a loaded question I suppose as we want this page to perform as quickly as possible.

Comment: There is also [curl_multi](http://se2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) you could use, which would do both at same time...

Comment: Well, we just need to get the information logged in two different clicky accounts. The information could be different, the real crux of the question is simply if we can make two calls to the API without making to remote requests. If curl_multi is a possibility an example solution would be much appreciated!

Comment: added an answer, let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with that API but if the API urls differ then yes your need to make 2 requests, if speed is important to you then you could use [curl_multi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php), which will make both requests at the same time. Which could speed up the return speed, but your still need to explode() each line into an array like file() does if you require that. So it might not make a huge difference, but heres an example:

```
<?php
function curl_multi($urls = array()) {
    $curl = array();
    $result = array();

    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    foreach ($urls as $id=>$url) {
        $curl[$id] = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl[$id], CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl[$id], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($curl[$id], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; curl)');
        curl_setopt($curl[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curl[$id]);
    }

    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while($running > 0);
    foreach($curl as $id=>$c) {
        $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
    }
    curl_multi_close($mh);
    return $result;
}

$urls['X'] = 'clicky API URL call to clicky id X';
$urls['Y'] = 'clicky API URL call to clicky id Y';

foreach(curl_multi($urls) as $id=>$result){
    $urls[$id] = explode(PHP_EOL, $result);
}
?>
```